# CSS Inner Container Width Issue

Tags: css

So I have a container and that container is set to '`width:40% !important`'. And there is an image inside that container and I'd like that image to be set to a width greater than 100% without using JavaScript. Is this possible?

```
<table class="templateContainer-header">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="url">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So templateContainer-header is set to 40% !important, width-wise, and img is set to 100% !important, there is no effect when I increase the width of the image to greater than 100%

Also, the styles are in-lined via the `roadie` gem

Comment: Sure it's possible, `<img src="" style="width: 200%;">` for instance. That seems so simple that it can't possibly be what you're asking for, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: Haha. I tried that and for some reason the image did not expand past 100%

Answer (score 1):

It should work as @thirtydot pointed. Just make the width wider than the container and it should work.

But if you're in a responsive page, the chances are that your images are all set to `max-width: 100%;` In this case you'll have to set `max-width:none` in this specific image, so it will overflow the container and not be reduced to fit it. Something like `.img-container img {max-width: none;}`.

See a example of how it should work: http://cdpn.io/plhGe